# To describe how to write a kanji, is it more useful to say the radical first, or the base kanji?

Tags: kanji, radicals

When explaining how to write a kanji verbally (by using radicals) is it more natural to say the radical, then the base kanji, or the other way around? Does it matter?:

> (1)「**てへん**」に「**しろ**」でできている漢字の、音読みと訓読みを言いなさい。
>   (2)「**しろ**」に「**てへん**」でできている漢字の、音読みと訓読みを言いなさい。
>
> (1) 「**さんずい**」に「**さき**」でできている漢字の、音読みと訓読みを言いなさい。
>   (2) 「**さき**」に「**さんずい**」でできている漢字の、音読みと訓読みを言いなさい。
>
> (1) 「**うかんむり**」に「**たに**」でできている漢字の、音読みと訓読みを言いなさい。
>   (2) 「**たに**」に「**うかんむり**」でできている漢字の、音読みと訓読みを言いなさい。

Does this drill seem like a natural way to learn radicals? Or are these more like trivia questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In speech people usually say the well-known radical first. 「てへんにしろ (=拍)」「さんずいにさき (=洗)」「うかんむりにたに (=容)」 sound perfect to me. しろにてへん is not wrong but sounds awkward.

述べなさい or 答えなさい is better than 言いなさい here, though.